# Does jQuery remove function really remove Dom elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am really wondering if jQuery **[remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)** function really remove elements from DOM.
First, I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185760/jquery-does-remove-really-remove) but the answers are not convincing.
I encountered this problem when I noticed I am still able to manipulate elements on which I have called remove function.

My code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div">
        This is a div
    </div>
</div>

var div = $('#div');
$('#div').remove();
$('#container').append(div);
```

**Note:** My question is not **how to solve this?** but I want to understand what's going on here!
Actually, this code doesn't remove the #div from the dom, but if I have any **data** set to the #div, it will be lost. I am pretty confused now about the behaviour of **remove** function. Can anyone explain this please?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VAUXG/1/)

I am convinced that div variable is not just a clone of the dom element, is a reference to it, because when I manipulate the div variable, (like **`div.html('something')`**) the **div** within the DOM get updated.
Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, http://api.jquery.com/remove/ Might unlock the mystery :))

Comment: as long as something refers to that object (stored in a variable), it's removed from the DOM, but never removed from the memory.

Comment: @Tats_innit Dude, do you really think I didn't read that before??

Comment: @skafandri sup man! just a comment bro, no sweat! B-)

Comment: @skafandri: There are **many** people who would not have read it in your shoes though.

Comment: If you read it, you missed the part about `detach()` removing the element from the DOM, but keeping the events and data intact ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`remove()` does indeed remove the element from the DOM.

However in your example, the element has been cached in memory because you assigned it to the `div` variable. Therefore you can still use it, and append it again, and it will still contain all the events the original did.

> If what you say is right, why I loose the data bound to the div so?

If you check the [source for remove()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.remove) you'll see that it calls the internal `cleanData` function which removes the events and clears the `data` cache for the element. This is why you lose the information.

If you want to remove the element from the DOM, but keep the elements, use `detach()` instead.

Here's a fiddle to show the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/2VbmX/

Comment: mmmm seems strange... div=reference to Dom !  and he removes the items from DOM. so if he tries to read div  - he should get div ->referencing to null !

Comment: If what you say is right, why I loose the **data** bound to the div so?

Comment: @skafandri: The data is kept in a separate object, not on the DOM element itself or its jQuery wrapper. Most likely if you `remove` something jQuery decides that it's gone for good and also removes the data it keeps for it to decrease memory usage. Keep in mind that jQuery does not know if your page is a rich app that creates and removes thousands of elements, so it has to be careful.

Comment: @skafandri I've updated my answer with an explanation for you

Comment: Actuall, I want to **remove everything** I'm not complaining about the data to be removed, but I want the element to be removed and not to be accessible anymore, a call to my variable **div** should return **undefinded** isn't it?

Comment: Well no, because it's in memory. If you don't want that variable to be accessible anymore you will have to set it to `null` manually when you remove the element from the DOM. Have a google for `reference type variables` to see why it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: I am convinced that **div** variable is not just a **clone** of the dom element, is a **reference** to is, because when I manipulate the **div** variable, (like div.html('something')) the div within the DOM get updated. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

had to delete the assigned variable:

```
delete div;
```