# Caching elements in jQuery (Internet Explorer?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script>
    var elem = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $elem = $("#elem");
        $("#parent").html('');
        $("#parent").append($elem);
    });
</script>

<div id="parent">
    <div>
        Bla Bla Bla...
    </div>
    <div id="elem">
        <div>
            It work's!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to cache the element with ID #elem with als his child nodes and text nodes and the text nodes of his child nodes. The code above works in Google Chrome and Firefox, but in Internet Explorer (tested with IE 10) the child nodes of #elem are missing.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try removing that $ selector from `$elem`

Comment: How is it even working in Chrome and FF ?

Comment: Probably a bug. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQcC3/). [result](http://jsfiddle.net/JQcC3/embedded/result/)

Comment: Here you have a similar question. See the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716684/does-jquery-remove-function-really-remove-dom-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I think this is a jQuery internal cloning/*coding* issue -- deep copy vs shallow copy!

Using

```
$elem = $('#elem').clone();
```

[works](http://jsfiddle.net/YNgqc/)!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) method of JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
$elem = $("#elem").clone();
```

it works for me on IE10