# Clear the rest of the DIVs after choosing from dropdown-list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the js i have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#box1').hide();
           $('#box2').hide();
           $('#box3').hide();
           $("#thechoices").change(function(){
              if(this.value == 'all'){
                     $("#boxes").children().show();
                  }else{
                     $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
                  }
           });          
           $("#thechoices").change(); 
        });
</script>
```

And the Html:

```
    <div id="boxes">
       <div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>
       <div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>
       <div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>
    </div>
```

I need to clear (empty) all the rest of the options after choosing from the dropdown-list,
(even if i opened the source code they won't appear) and disable the dropdown-list in the same time,

how to achieve that?

Comment: do you want to remove them from the page completely or just make them blank. if u want to make them blank do something like:
$('#thechoices').empty();

Comment: And, javascript (jquery) can't remove elements from the source, only the DOM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185760/jquery-does-remove-really-remove

Comment: and yes he's right it won't remove it from the source, only the dom

Comment: I want to remove them from the page completely

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thechoices').change(function(){
        $(this).empty();
    });
});
```

Comment: That will get rid of all of the options, not just the ones that he doesn't want.

Comment: @RuralJuror
"I need to clear (empty) all the rest of the options after choosing from the dropdown-list" - OP

Comment: Read it again, clown: "*rest* of the options, not all of the options..." -OP