# Removing an element

Tags: jquery, html

An element is removed from the html file with the following code,

```
$("#sample").remove();
```

When view the source code, the removed element still appear in the source code. Whether it is possible to remove the element from the source code?

Comment: If it is getting removed from the html then why are you concerned from removing it from source code?

Comment: I think the OP is talking about the rendered HTML in developer tools.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185760/jquery-does-remove-really-remove

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *not possible to remove element from source control* using script on client like javascript. It is removed from DOM and wont participate in rendering and wont be accessible through script.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is static. It is simply the code that was used to load the page. Modifying the DOM does will NOT affect the source code. Just as adding to the DOM will also NOT add to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

i will agree with Adil, it's not possible through the scripting language i.e. javascript/jquery...

```
$("#sample").empty();
//will not work...
```